# How can I plot the launchment of a body in 3D in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, physics

**Question**.

> Create a function `drawparabolicshot.m` that represents the parabolic shot in 3D knowing that the function has as input the angles `O` and `phi`, according to the following expressions:
>
> ```
> x=vo*cos(O)*cos(phi)*t,
> y=vo*cos(O)*sin(phi)*t, and
> z=vo*sin(O)*t-(g/2)*t^2.
> ```
>
> At the moment of representing the function, use `plot3` and `pause` to see how it draws the parabolic trajectory, having fixed previously `xlim`, `ylim` and `zlim`.

**Attempt.**

```
function dibujatiroparabolico(phi, O)

vo=100;      %example of vo
g=9.8;        
tmax=(2*vo*sin(O))/(g);
i=1;

for t=linspace(0,tmax)
x(i)=vo*cos(phi)*cos(O)*t;
y(i)=vo*cos(O)*sin(phi)*t;
z(i)=vo*sin(O)*t-(g/2)*t.^2;
i=i+1;
hold on
pause on
plot3(x,y,z)
end
```

**Issue**. But it plots a straight line, without showing how it builds and in 2 dimensions even though I used `plot3`.

What happens when I plot it with examples of `phi=pi` and `O=pi/4`:

**New Edit.**

```
function dibujatiroparabolico(phi, O)

vo=100;
g=9.8;
tmax=(2*vo*sin(O))./(g);
i=1;

for t=linspace(0,tmax)
x(i)=vo*cos(phi)*cos(O)*t;
y(i)=vo*cos(O)*sin(phi)*t;
z(i)=vo*sin(O)*t-(g/2)*t.^2;
i=i+1;
pause(0.1)
plot3(x,y,z)
xlim([0 tmax*vo*cos(O)*cos(phi)])
ylim([0 tmax*vo*cos(O)*sin(phi)])
zlim([0 vo*sin(O)*(tmax/2)-(g/2)*(tmax/2).^2])
hold on
end
```

[image: What happens when I plot it with examples of phi=pi and O=pi/4]

Comment: Put the `hold on` after your first use of `plot3`.

Comment: thank you that helps but still don't know how to set up the limits AND the fact that it still doesn't show point by point. (The limits are supposed to be worked with physics, ie knowing that xlim will go from 0 to the value of x when it hits the ground again (tmax), same with y, while with zlim will go from 0 to the value of z at tmax/2, since that is when it will be at the top.)

Comment: oh, if i write pause(0.1) it does show up step by step, but then why do we have to write pause on? + still don't know how to set up the limits.

Comment: Don't use `pause on`. Use `xlim()`, `ylim()` and `zlim()` to set the limits of the plot area.

Comment: I think I got it, is it this (new edit to the post)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided do not work for me because cos(phi) is -1 when phi = pi. `xlim()` wants the limits in the order [min mix], so I corrected your code with xlim(sort([0 tmax*vo*cos(O)*cos(phi)])). This should be robust to any values of phi and O.

When running this code, I get an animation of the "projectile" flying across the plotting window, with fixed limits.

```
dibujatiroparabolico(pi, pi/4)

function dibujatiroparabolico(phi, O)

vo=100;
g=9.8;
tmax=(2*vo*sin(O))./(g);
i=1;

    for t=linspace(0,tmax)
        x(i)=vo*cos(phi)*cos(O)*t;
        y(i)=vo*cos(O)*sin(phi)*t;
        z(i)=vo*sin(O)*t-(g/2)*t.^2;
        i=i+1;
        plot3(x,y,z)
        xlim(sort([0 tmax*vo*cos(O)*cos(phi)]))
        ylim(sort([0 tmax*vo*cos(O)*sin(phi)]))
        zlim(sort([0 vo*sin(O)*(tmax/2)-(g/2)*(tmax/2).^2]))
        pause(0.1)
        hold on
    end
end
```